New pixelate node smooths pixels in viewport and I don't know how to disable it
I switched from blender 4.0 to blender 4.1.1 and the pixelate node was updated. Now it smooths everything out (in viewport) and it looks terrible. Perhaps I missed a setting somewhere that allows you to disable antialiasing in viewport.


I'm sorry, but there must be something else different in your settings. I've checked with the rendered output of a Render Layers node and a previously save PNG image, my results in 4.0.2 and 4.1.1 are the same, so I cannot really reproduce your problem. Could you upload your file here https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions to edit it into your question? Make sure any external textures are packed into the file.

It seems to work for me too, I just haven’t tried rendering. Is there a way to make it appear unsmoothed in the viewport? Because I don't want to render, I want to record video directly from the viewport. I added the file to the question

Maybe you should have told this earlier about the viewport. The viewport compositing is far from perfect and does not work exactly like real compositing a render. Since rendering with the Pixelate does not show a difference, I guess it's not the new node itself, but maybe how the viewport display or viewport compositing works now. I have no idea how to change that. But if you do not use the Scale nodes and instead switch the Pixelate node to a Pixel Size of let's say 1/0.13 ≈ 8 (pixels have to be integers of course) it looks at least a bit better.
